# Codeigniter file uploading issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to upload image files using codeigniter 3 but it's not working. No matter what I do, it always says "You didn't select a file to upload". It logs an error on the console saying error 500 when i click on the error in the Network tab then it redirects me to a new tab where it says that error.
Here is my HTML Code:

```
<div id="container">
<h1>Welcome to CodeIgniter!</h1>

<div id="body">
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo base_url('index.php/welcome/upload'); ?>">
        <input type="text" name="username" value="Zahid Saeed">
        <input type="file" name="profile_img">
        <button type="submit">Submit Form</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

and here is my controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper("url");
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
    public function upload() {  

        $config = array(
            "upload_path" => "./uploads/",
            "allowed_types" => "gif|jpg|png"
        );
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($this->input->post());
        print_r($_FILES);
        echo "</pre>";

        $this->load->library("upload", $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if(!$this->upload->do_upload("profile_img")) {
            echo $this->upload->display_errors();
            echo "IN IF";
        }
        else {
            echo "img uploaded successfully";
        }

    }
}
```

One more thing, the exact code is working on the linux machine and in fact on the server. But it's not working on my laptop. I'm using Windows 8.1

Thanks in Advance

Comment: i am facing this problem right now with ci 3.1.2

Comment: Exactly I'm using the same version !

Comment: am stuck with this  -> 500 internal server error.

Comment: Me too. Any idea why is it happening?

Comment: did u use any .htaccess file for hiding index.php????

Comment: i don't know dear, may be some pros will help us... anyway try try.....

Comment: I used it earlier but now I commented it out. 1 thing that i noted is the base_url in the config.php file. If you change it, form behavior changes sometimes.

Comment: ok, share the codes when u get the correct answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129003/discussion-between-zahid-saeed-and-bibin-john).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[may be its php.ini problem](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/4887)

Open your php.ini file

search for  extension=php_fileinfo.dll

if you are using xampp it may be commented by default

```
change 
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll

to

extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

and restart your xampp...

this was solve my problem

Comment: Thank you so much. This really solved my issue. I didn't know why it happened. It is enabled by default. Anyway, thank you once again :)

Answer (score 0):

Might be a good idea to use absolute paths for your upload path

```
$this->upload_config['upload_path'] = FCPATH . 'uploads/';
```

When I run your code, it works under **WAMP64 on Windows 10 Home**, ie the file is uploaded and I get to see

```
Array
(
    [username] => Zahid Saeed
)
Array
(
    [profile_img] => Array
        (
            [name] => header-background.png
            [type] => image/png
            [tmp_name] => C:\wamp64\tmp\php34DA.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 563
        )

)

img uploaded successfully
```

Comment: It founds the directory but it says "You didn't select a file to upload" even when i select a file. If it was directory error it gave an error: "The upload path doesn't appear to be valid"

Comment: ok, Well I am using your code and it works fine... I've tried a few things to break it and I cannot get it to generate the error you are seeing which isn't very useful... So what are you getting in your Debug Output

Comment: It says: "You didn't select a file to upload" and throws an error 500

Comment: I'm at a bit of a loss. I'm running your code on WAMP on Windows 10 (shhh don't tell anyone I am using Windows!)

Comment: What version of codeigniter are you using? Please try to use version 3.1.2 and then try again

Comment: I was on CI 3.1.0, just tried it on CI 3.1.2 and it works. But you had it working on Linux... What are you using for a local server on Winows 8.1?

Comment: I'm using XAMPP

Answer (score 0):

//check here if file is not empty
if(!empty($_FILES['attach_file']['name'])){
     $config['upload_path'] = APPPATH.'../assets/images/'; $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|mp4'; $config['file_name'] = 'attach_file_'.time(); $config['max_size'] = "1024";$config['max_height']= "800";$config['max_width'] = "1280";$config['overwrite'] = false;$this->upload->initialize($config);if(!($this->upload->do_upload("attach_file"))){$data['error']['attach_file'] = $this->upload->display_errors();else{ $coverPhotoData = $this->upload->data(); $coverPhoto =$coverPhotoData['file_name'];}}elseif($this->input->get('cup')){$coverPhoto = $previous['attach_file'];}

Answer (score 0):

**This code not supporting obj and fbx formats for file uploading what i do change for this**

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper("url");
}

public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('welcome_message');
}
public function upload() {  

    $config = array(
        "upload_path" => "./uploads/",
        "allowed_types" => "gif|jpg|png"
    );
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($this->input->post());
    print_r($_FILES);
    echo "</pre>";

    $this->load->library("upload", $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if(!$this->upload->do_upload("profile_img")) {
        echo $this->upload->display_errors();
        echo "IN IF";
    }
    else {
        echo "img uploaded successfully";
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. StackOverflow is not a discussion form. If you are going to post an answer please make sure it is an answer. Please read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to get a better understand of what an answer is. Please also go through the site [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)